# Сравнение чисел типа Integer в ArrayList с помощью == и equals()

Tags: java

Задача: 1) ввести 10 цифр с клавиатуры, 2) вывести длину самой длинной последовательности повторяющихся чисел в списке.

> Пример для списка 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 4, 23, 1:
>
> ВЫВОД: 3

Теперь вопрос: почему программа не выводит корректную длину (для чисел больше 128)  последовательности если в данной строке применяем "=="?

```
if (list.get(i) == list.get(i + 1))
```

если же написать

```
if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1)))
```

вывод будет корректным и для чисел больше 128

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int max = 1;
        int maximum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            list.add(n);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
                max++;
                if (max > maximum){
                    maximum = max;
                }
            }
            else
                if (max > maximum){
                maximum = max;
                max = 1;
            }
                else
                    max = 1;
        }
        System.out.println(maximum);
    }
```

Comment: В ArrayList<> хранится Integer, который является наследником Object. А при сравнении объектов оператором == сравниваются ссылки, а не значение. Использование метода equals - правильное.

Comment: `==` для примитивов, `equals()` для обьектов. Делайте принудительный unboxing и будет `==` работать.

Comment: А почему работает до 128, здесь описано https://vijayanbu001.blogspot.com/2016/07/identity-vs-equality-comparison-of.html